# Add UI View to Storyboard

Tags: xcode, swift, facebook-ios-sdk, xcode-storyboard

Noob XCode/Swift question here. I'm trying to add Facebook login to a [demo app and am stuck on step 11](http://www.brianjcoleman.com/tutorial-facebook-login-in-swift/), "Add a UIView to your Storyboard and hookup the outlet of the view to fbLoginView."

I do control + drag the reference outlet to the view controller but this doesn't create the link. I done this drag to connect before but with Object library elements I've added myself to the storyboard. What I'm not sure about is how to do it if the code, i.e., `@IBOutlet var fbLoginView : FBLoginView!` is already in my view controller.

Answer (score 5):

I have tried this tutorial and found a solution for you all you need to do is Click on you UIView and set the class name **FBLoginView** Like this Way:

[image]

After that you can connect your outlet this way:

First click on UIView in your storyBoard after that connect the Outlet

[image]

and you will find `fbLoginView`.

May be this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Then try and click on "View Controller" on the left and see if the outlet is available on the right under connections inspector. If it is then just drag it straight to the view to link it, else it needs to be added in the code, but seens as though you already said you did that it seems overly pedantic to even mention.